# eclipselink PersistenceUnitLoadingEception in WAR file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, eclipselink, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I'm getting an extremely similar error to this question: [eclipselink PersistenceUnitLoadingEception in executable JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329608/eclipselink-persistenceunitloadingeception-in-executable-jar).

I am deploying on WAS Liberty Profile V8.5.

When exporting my project to a WAR file however; I do not have the option of changing packaging. I'm not sure what is wrong and what the difference between packaging styles is. Even then...all my dependencies (jar files) are in a directory that is specified in server.xml, so suffice to say I am baffled.

Error:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [websphere.jaxrs.filters.ProjectAccessFilter] filter did not load during start up.
SRVE0320E: The [websphere.jaxrs.filters.ProjectAccessFilter] filter was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [websphere.jaxrs.filters.AuthorizationFilter] filter did not load during start up.
SRVE0320E: The [websphere.jaxrs.filters.AuthorizationFilter] filter was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0320E: The [websphere.jaxrs.filters.AuthorizationFilter] filter was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred.
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:615)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0320E: The [websphere.jaxrs.filters.AuthorizationFilter] filter was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred.
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.validateAndRun(WebApp.java:860)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.validateAndRun(WebApp.java:847)
    ... 1 more
Caused by (repeated) ... : Exception [EclipseLink-30009] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140222-22988a5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while trying to load persistence unit at url: jar:file:/C:/wlp/usr/servers/dropServer/apps/WebApiConsole.war!/
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140222-22988a5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing persistence.xml from URL: jar:file:/C:/wlp/usr/servers/dropServer/apps/WebApiConsole.war!/
Internal Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:619)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:610)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:636)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:524)
```

When I unzip my war file, the location of my persistence.xml file is:
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
There is also: /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

I'm not sure if this makes a difference or to tell eclipse to stop making this extra META-INF folder.

Interestingly, when I simply build my project and use a .xml extension to refer to my classes, it works perfectly! (Note, this is the default way when you simple press 'run on server').

WebApiConsole.war.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archive>
    <dir sourceOnDisk="C:\eclipse\workspace\WebApiConsole\WebContent" targetInArchive="/"/>
    <dir sourceOnDisk="C:\eclipse\workspace\WebApiConsole\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes" targetInArchive="/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</archive>
```

Here is the filter file:

```
@WebFilter(description = "This filter intercepts all requests to the restful"
        + "webservice and checks whether the user is in the database", urlPatterns = { "/rest/*" })
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String identifierCookieDomain = "null";
    private static final String identifierCookieName = "UID";
    private EntityManager em;

    public AuthorizationFilter() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ConsoleManagement").createEntityManager();
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Cookie[] cookies;
        String uid = null;

        cookies = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getCookies();
        if ( cookies == null ) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(401, "Unauthorized Access: Please login");
        } else {

            uid = getCookie(request, identifierCookieDomain, identifierCookieName);

            if ( uid == null || !userExists(uid)) {
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(401, "Unauthorized Access: Please login");
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }   
        }
    }

    public boolean userExists(String uid) {
        List<User> users = em.createNamedQuery("User.queryUserByUid", User.class)
                .setParameter("uid", uid)
                .getResultList();
        if (users.size() == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getCookie(ServletRequest request, String domain, String name) {
        String value = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getCookies();
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            String cookieDomain = cookie.getDomain() == null ? "null" : cookie.getDomain();
            String cookieName = cookie.getName() == null ? "null" : cookie.getName();
            if ( cookieDomain.equals(domain) &&
                    cookieName.equals(name) ) {
                value = cookie.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

}
```

Comment: Are you using jpa-2.1 in a Liberty beta, or are you packaging EclipseLink yourself and using jpa-2.0 in a specific Liberty release?  (Which version is displayed at the top of messages.log?)

Comment: I have jpa-2.1 feature turned on. I'm sorry, but there is no version that I could find at the top of messages.log.

Answer (score 0):

This look like an EclipseLink bug. Can you post something to the [EclipseLink users](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/eclipselink-users) mailing list? I'll follow up with you over there.

**[Update]**

After debugging the problem, it is a problem in WebSphere Liberty that has been fixed in the [Beta that was announced on 8/15/2014.](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/?p=9955&preview=1&_ppp=a8046aab66)

**[/Update]**

Comment: As requested, I posted the issue.

Comment: I don't see it on the list yet... I think you have to be subscribed before it'll let you post.

Comment: Interesting... I will subscribe. Done. I apologize, gmail filtered the failure into promotions